# mysqli_stmt_get_result() replacing

Tags: php, mysqli

here's my code I use on my local "development" server, but unfortunately my remote server doesn't support mysqli native driver - how is it possible to replace `mysqli_stmt_get_result();`?

CODE:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect,$query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$nickname,$password);
        mysqli_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        include("year_tester.php");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != ""){
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['loginName'] = $nickname;
            $_SESSION['classIdentify'] = $rocnik.".".$className;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

...is it acceptable to rewrite it in PDO? :p

```
    $pdoh=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8",
    $mysqldb_username,$mysqldb‌​_password,
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
    //$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect,$query);
    $pdosh=$pdoh->prepare($query);
    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$nickname,$password);
    //i feel sorry for the guy writing the garabage collector :(
    $pdosh->bindParam(1,$nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdosh->bindParam(2,$password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //mysqli_execute($stmt);
    $pdosh->execute(); //using ERRMODE_EXCEPTION right?
    //$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $row=$pdosh->fetch();
    require("year_tester.php");
    if($pdosh->rowCount()>0/*mysqli_num_rows($result) != ""*/){
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
        $_SESSION['loginName'] = $nickname;
        $_SESSION['classIdentify'] = $rocnik.".".$className;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /data/web/virtuals/30268/virtual/www/subdom/beta/functions.php

Comment: $pdoh is supposed to be like this
$pdoh=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8",$mysqldb_username,$mysqldb_password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));